# Custom logout implementations with Spring and refresh token

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I created a custom logout implementation with `jwt` and `refresh token`, so far I tested it with `Postman` and logout function works fine there, I can logout user. Right now I'm trying to create a button inside `html` and after user click on it user should be logged out. Below down is my `logout` implementation and part of `html` code that I tried so far.

**Result is:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not 
supported
```

---

`Logout` implementation

```
@PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(@RequestBody TokenDTO dto) {
        String refreshTokenString = dto.getRefreshToken();
        if (jwtHelper.validateRefreshToken(refreshTokenString) && refreshTokenRepository.existsById(jwtHelper.getTokenIdFromRefreshToken(refreshTokenString))) {
            // valid and exists in db
            refreshTokenRepository.deleteById(jwtHelper.getTokenIdFromRefreshToken(refreshTokenString));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid token");
    }
```

That works fine in postman when I put refreshToken that is created as `"refreshToken":"token..."` but right now I'm trying to create actually button that will logout user when he clicks it.

In html page I added somethig like this:

```
<button id="logout" class="float-left submit-button">Log out</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("logout").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/logout";
  };
</script>
```

But when I click on button nothing is happening, how I can achieve my goal with my custom implementation logout?

Answer (score 0):

here with button click you are firing get request instead of expected post one. That's why it's complaining.

Instead you can do xhr post request for this case.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#example_post

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a get request on the button click event.
This can be sorted in two ways:
first, you can change the logout mapping to @GetMapping like below

```
@GetMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(@RequestBody TokenDTO dto) {
        String refreshTokenString = dto.getRefreshToken();
        if (jwtHelper.validateRefreshToken(refreshTokenString) && refreshTokenRepository.existsById(jwtHelper.getTokenIdFromRefreshToken(refreshTokenString))) {
            // valid and exists in db
            refreshTokenRepository.deleteById(jwtHelper.getTokenIdFromRefreshToken(refreshTokenString));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid token");
    }
```

second, location.href only sends the get request.
You can change the button to form like this:

```
<form action="/logout" method="POST">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

this will sort the issue